# How do I fix the Value Error in my Bilateral Filter?

Tags: python, image, image-processing

I am trying to implement a bilateral filter but I am getting an error

```
def bilateral_filter(image, sigma_spatial, sigma_range, window_size):
    # Compute the spatial filter
    spatial_filter = nd.gaussian_filter(np.ones(window_size), sigma_spatial)
    # Compute the intensity (range) filter
    intensity_range = image.max() - image.min()
    intensity_filter = np.exp(-0.5 * ((np.arange(256) - image[..., np.newaxis]) / sigma_range) ** 2)

    # Compute the bilateral filter
    filtered_image = np.zeros_like(image)
    for i in range(image.shape[0]):
        for j in range(image.shape[0]):
            i_min = max(0, i - window_size[0] // 2)
            i_max = min(image.shape[0], i + window_size[0] // 2 + 1)
            j_min = max(0, j - window_size[1] // 2)
            j_max = min(image.shape[1], j + window_size[1] // 2 + 1)

            spatial_weights = spatial_filter[i_min - i + window_size[0] // 2:i_max - i + window_size[0] // 2,
                              j_min - j + window_size[1] // 2:j_max - j + window_size[1] // 2]
            intensity_weights = intensity_filter[(image[i_min:i_max, j_min:j_max] - image[i, j]).astype(int) + 128]
            weights = spatial_weights * intensity_weights
            normalized_weights = weights / np.sum(weights)
            filtered_image[i, j] = np.sum(normalized_weights * image[i_min:i_max, j_min:j_max])

    return filtered_image
```

Here is the error

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,4,8) (5,5,512,256)
```

It says it is in this line

```
weights = spatial_weights * intensity_weights
```

Window size is (8,8,8)

I am trying to process a 512x512 image with gauss noise

Comment: If your image is 2D, why do you have a 3D window? Please include the code you use to call this function, so we know the types and values of the inputs. See [mre]. And copy-paste the full error message l, including the stack trace.